What if Pinchas didn’t kill for the sake of heaven
In Parashat Chukat/Pinchas we learn of the story of Pinchas killing Zimri and Cozbi after the Halacha being revealed to him
We know from various commentators that he did this act with tremendous love for Hashem and without any personal emotions or ego. There is tremendous emphasis on his dedication of the mitzvah to Hashem and not for any personal means
I am wondering, if someone in this situation would not do it for the sake of heaven and was rather doing it for personal reasons, would it be allowed? And if it was publicly obvious that he wasn’t doing it for the sake of heaven would he get punished? Or is a mitzvah that requires no kavanah?

https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA:%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%92%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%95#%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99

I'd say, there's no clear answer because circumstances matter. Halachicly speaking, laying with a shiktze results in corporal rather than capital punishment, but, based on the severity of the situation, a theoretical Beis Din can convict the killer of murder or exonerate.

Thanks @shmosel, that is fascinating! I don’t think I can mark a comment as accepted but please translate and post as answer so others can learn from it and I can mark as accepted, thanks for sharing

Pinchas followed the halachic principle that with respect to certain severe sins (and with various caveats), קנאים פוגעים בו, "zealots may strike him." According to the sources cited here, it's an absolute prerequisite that it be done purely for the sake of heaven. Otherwise, the attacker is not a zealot but a common murderer. That said, it wouldn't be possible to execute the attacker, nor one who killed the attacker to save the perpetrator, because there's no way to definitively prove his internal state of mind.
